# Mysql : Get relative complement from two tables that updated one day before

Tags: mysql, timestamp, subquery

I have two tables which I will call A and B, and both has similar data but in different field. I'm trying to get data from A table and it should be does not exist in table B, but there is one condition. There is a field for timestamp indicates when does people updated this data, and I have to get data updated yesterday. I know how to get relative complement using subquery, but If I use subquery I can't put condition to filter timestamp. Is there any way to get relative complement while giving condition of time?

This is database A                      database B

```
 ID  |   timestamp              |    ID  |   timestamp              |
 --------------------------------    --------------------------------
 1   |   2017-01-01 00:00:00    |    1   |   2017-01-01 00:00:00    |
 2   |   2017-01-04 00:00:00    |    8   |   2017-01-04 00:00:00    |
 3   |   2017-01-11 00:00:00    |    9   |   2017-01-11 00:00:00    | 
 4   |   2017-01-14 00:00:00    |    4   |   2017-01-14 00:00:00    |
 5   |   2017-01-07 00:00:00    |    5   |   2017-01-07 00:00:00    |
```

This is query I tried.

```
SELECT a.id FROM a as a
WHERE a.id not in (SELECT b.a_id FROM b as b) AND a.timestamp IS NOT NULL;
```

This is condition that I would like to give

```
where timestamp >= date_add(now(), interval -1 day)
```

Comment: I think you might want to use date_sub instead of date_add. For example: date_sub(now(), interval 1 day).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should work fine, granted you actually have a date in your timestamp field whose value is today or greater.  Below are two different queries you can use.

```
select a.*
  from your_schema.your_table a
  left join your_schema.your_table_2 b
    on b.id = a.id
 where a.id > 0
   and b.id is null
   and a.checktime >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day);
```

**OR**

```
select *
  from your_schema.your_table
 where id not in (select id
                    from your_schema.your_table_2)
   and checktime >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day);
```